# Why do BeautifulSoup and multiprocessing raise an index out of range in a list?

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

I'm trying to parse a page using BeautifulSoup. This is the function where the exception is thrown:

```
def get_page_items(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    name = 
    soup.find(class_="ccpProductDetail__title__text").text.strip()
    price = soup.find(attrs={"data-price-main" : "price-main"}).text.strip()
    images_routes_src = soup.find_all(class_="ccpProductDetailSlideshow__slider__wrapper__list__item__image")
    images_routes = []

    try:
        for image in images_routes_src:
        images_routes.append(image['src'].strip())
    except:
        pass


    description_html = soup.find_all(class_="block large")
    description_html[0].div.decompose()
    new_tag = soup.new_tag("h3")
    new_tag.string = 'Hinweise'
    description_html[2].span.replace_with(new_tag)

    beschreibung_html = soup.find(class_="block large text")

    description_html.insert(1, beschreibung_html)

    item = Item(name, price, images_routes, description_html)

return item
```

And this is where the method is called using a pool:

```
for index, page in enumerate(pages_urls):
    if page is not pages_urls[-len(pages_urls)]:
        init_BeautifulSoup(pages_urls[index])
    get_all_page_item_links()
    page_items = pool.map(get_page_items, items_urls)
    total_items.extend(page_items)
```

This is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rodrigopeniche/Documents/workspace/WebScraping/conrad_scrapping (4).py", line 120, in <module>
    page_items = pool.map(get_page_items, items_urls)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've seen in many other posts that sometimes this happens with multiprocessing, but I've tried calling the function in a for loop and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rodrigopeniche/Documents/workspace/WebScraping/conrad_scrapping (4).py", line 123, in <module>
    page_items.append(get_page_items(url))
  File "/Users/rodrigopeniche/Documents/workspace/WebScraping/conrad_scrapping (4).py", line 78, in get_page_items
    description_html[0].div.decompose()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I only try to do this with a random element of the list the script runs without errors, for example as following:

```
 get_all_page_item_links()
 item = get_page_items(items_urls[3])
 print item.description_html
```

What's going on there?

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify if `description_html` has any value within it? `line 78, in get_page_items`

```
>>> foo = []
>>> foo[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I suggest adding an if condition.

```
description_html = soup.find_all(class_="block large")
if description_html:
    description_html[0].div.decompose()
    new_tag = soup.new_tag("h3")
    new_tag.string = 'Hinweise'
    description_html[2].span.replace_with(new_tag)
else:
    pass
    # Do something here

beschreibung_html = soup.find(class_="block large text")
if beschreibung_html:
    description_html.insert(1, beschreibung_html)
    item = Item(name, price, images_routes, description_html)
else:
    pass
    # do something here
```

Comment: this doesn't work, there's always a NoneValue somewhere, it's weird because none of the list elements when accessed one by one randomly raise any errors, but when the whole list is passed in a loop or in a pool this happens

Comment: tbh I am not familiar with the `soup` library, though the error ,`IndexError`,  is pretty straightforward. Have you verified what the value of `description_html` is prior the exception? Maybe add a log.debug prior `line 78, in get_page_items` or print it out?